# TextField getting content cleared out on backspace

Tags: ios6, textfield, backspace

I have set-up in a `storyboard` a view that contents two `textfields`: one with secure option turn on and an other without.

I have set-up the content of those `textfields` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the associated viewController. If I select the textField with secure note turned on then select the other one and click the backspace all its content of this latter gets clear out.  It is not happening if I select directly the textfield with no secure option the first time.

Does anyone have a clue of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug that appeared on `iOS6` and related to changes introduce with `UITextField` where other people have also observed changes in behavior between `iOS5` and `iOS6`; see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400724/backspace-functionality-in-ios-6-ios-5-for-uitextfield-with-secure-attribute): (Backspace functionality in iOS 6 & iOS 5 for UITextfield with 'secure' attribute)