# how to detect backspace of numeric keyboard on a secured textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, numeric-keypad

Hi I have a need to detect backspace button event on textfield.

Common way to detect the backspace is to add the whitespace and see the changed text.

But 
As the textfield is secured textfield.adding the whitespace trick won't work out.

Any helpful suggestions are welcome

### Edit - don't close :

This is not a duplicate question because its about doing it on secured textfield  and this is not a duplicate of below questions

[Detect backspace in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1977934/7621990)

[How to detect delete key on an UITextField in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25371254/7621990)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371254/how-to-detect-delete-key-on-an-uitextfield-in-ios-8

Comment: Are you asking about detecting when text is deleted or when the backspace is tapped when the textfield is already empty?

Comment: @rmaddy - Yes,in a secured textfield

Comment: So you need to do both things I asked about in my comment?

Comment: just when backspace is pressed not necessary a text has to be removed... i should be able to detect even when textbox is empty

Comment: @rmaddy - any idea how it can be done in a secured textbox

Comment: Isn't your question a duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16765334/2415822 (Or some of the other linked questions in that question)